# Excel: Create formula for 3-card poker straights

Tags: microsoft-excel

Deck of 52 cards, 3-card poker game, where Straights are all three consecutive ranks, and in addition A,2,3.

I have numbered all cards, starting from 1 to 52. 
(Spades, A,K,...,2: 1,2,..13; Hearts A,K,...,2: 14,15,...26, and so on).

I created all possible combinations list:

1,2,3
1,2,4
...
1,51,52
...
50,51,52

Now, I wanted to create the formula that tells me if the cards form straight or not.

My attempt was: IF(AND(MOD(A2,13)-MOD(B2,13)=1,MOD(B2,13)-MOD(C2,13)=1),"Straight","")

But it gives me the incorrect total of possible straights. I know I am missing A,2,3 combs, but even if I include, I am still short of the target.

Any improvement suggestions on my formula, please?

Comment: If you haven't sorted the numbers in A2:C2 in **descending** order, you won't get an answer of 1 from your subtractions.

Comment: That's right. I have modified the formula: =IF(OR(AND(MOD(C2,13)-MOD(B2,13)=1,MOD(C2,13)-MOD(A2,13)=2),AND(MOD(C2,13)-MOD(B2,13)=2,MOD(C2,13)-MOD(A2,13)=1),AND(MOD(B2,13)-MOD(A2,13)=1,MOD(B2,13)-MOD(C2,13)=2),AND(MOD(B2,13)-MOD(A2,13)=2,MOD(B2,13)-MOD(C2,13)=1),AND(MOD(A2,13)-MOD(B2,13)=1,MOD(A2,13)-MOD(C2,13)=2),AND(MOD(A2,13)-MOD(B2,13)=2,MOD(A2,13)-MOD(C2,13)=1)),2,"") - however, I get lots of AK2 hands and not A23 hands. My worry is that total number (704) is still short of overall target of 720.

Comment: How do you figure 720?  If there are 48 choices for the first card (KA2 is not allowed, but presumably QKA and A23 are - that's 12 for each suit) times 4 choices for the second card times 4 for the third gives 768.  If, for whatever reason, there's only 11 first choices, that gives 704.  So your answer *might* be correct, depending on how you defined the problem.

Comment: 12 Cards for the Straight Starter (the smallest card), times 4 suits = 48, times 4 suits for the next card and 4 more for the last card, total of 768 combs. We must subtract all Straight Flushes, that is 48 combination and we have 720 combinations for straights.

Comment: I got it. I missed the 2,3,4 combs because their MOD(x,13) would be respectively: 0,11,12 and it will not suit the formula.

Comment: I should be able to your formula by also using the =LARGE() function. This would replace the use of your OR

Comment: Could you bring an example, please?